# To run a GraphQL server in Python that allows queries and subscriptions, do I have to combine it with a web framework service?

Tags: strawberry-graphql

Excuse my ignorance in this area: most of my programming has been in optimization and research. I am very new to GraphQL and client-server programming.

My organization is working on an automated scheduler in Python 3.9 for scheduling observations for a large-scale telescope.

We are relying on many different services to all communicate via GraphQL. At the moment, I am trying to implement a GraphQL server that can be queried or accept subscriptions to disseminate when a new schedule for the night is created (for any number of reasons such as changing weather conditions, instrument faults, modifications to observations). Eventually, we will need to allow mutations (e.g. to the priority of observations, or to fix an observation at a given time).

I am looking at both Strawberry and Graphene as my possible options, but what is unclear to me is if I require them to be combined with a web framework service like Django or Flask to achieve the functionality that I need.

I see that Strawberry has a built-in (possibly only debug) server, but it also discusses integration with Django, Flask, and others, and I am not certain if I need to go to that level. I have been working through examples and completed a JavaScript course using Apollo Server / Client, but I'm not sure how these compare to Python GraphQL server implementations.

I apologize for my lack of knowledge: I am trying to keep the project as simple as possible for now, and having played around with Graphene and Django, I'm not sure if I'm overcomplicating things of if this approach is necessary.

Statements like "Graphene is fully featured with integrations for the most popular web frameworks and ORMs" lead me to believe a web framework is required, but again, I am not sure and feel very out of my depth since in this area is virtually nonexistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of Strawberry GraphQL

For both Strawberry and Graphene you'd need framework like Django or Flask.

Strawberry has support for Subscriptions when using an ASGI framework like Starlette or FastAPI, there's some example here: https://strawberry.rocks/docs/general/subscriptions#subscriptions

We also have an almost-done PR that adds support for subscriptions using django: https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry/pull/1407

Comment: Thank you so much, Patrick. This is really appreciated and will be very useful.

Comment: you're welcome! feel free to jump over Strawberry's discord (link on the website) if you want to chat :)